# Drupal 8: How do I customize a form widget to show an entity field value instead of the entity title?

Tags: php, drupal, module, widget, drupal-8

I'm taking my first steps in understanding how Drupal 8 works under the hood by developing a custom form widget module. My goal is to show a referenced node's image field value, instead of its node title in a radio button list (available in core). This will allow website admins to select a picture instead of text when choosing a background image for a node.

Here's how my form looks without a custom work, using Drupal 8's built-in "Check boxes/radio buttons" widget:

[image: Drupal 8's built-in "Check boxes/radio buttons" widget example]

Here's a Photoshop mockup of how I want my custom widget to appear (at least to start):

[image: Photoshop mockup of how I want my custom widget to appear]

So far I've been able to create a starting module that extends the "Check boxes/radio buttons" widget, referencing the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module and traversing core. This has at helped me understand Drupal 8's module structure a little better at the least.

Module structure:

```
modules
  custom
    back_image_widget
      back_image_widget.info.yml
      back_image_widget.module
      src
        Plugin
          Field
            Field Widget
              BackImageWidget.php
```

back_image_widget.info.yml:

```
name: Background Image Entity Widget
type: module
description: Used to list Background Image entities as images instead of text labels in the Text Message content type form.
package: Custom
core: 8.x
```

back_image_widget.module:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Used to list Background Image entities as images instead of text labels in the Text Message content type form.
 */
```

BackImageWidget.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\back_image_widget\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget.
 */

namespace Drupal\back_image_widget\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OptionsButtonsWidget;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'field_back_image' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "field_back_image",
 *   module = "back_image_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("Background Image Entity"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "entity_reference"
 *   },
 *   multiple_values = FALSE
 * )
 */
class BackImageWidget extends OptionsButtonsWidget {

  //Here we go!

}
```

With that, I'm able to install the module, select the new widget, and have all expected functionality that core offers to start.

From here, I'm having troubles identifying the best pieces from parent classes to alter so that I can replace titles with other entity values. The most helpful functions seem to be protected. The resulting options return protected titles (without other information available such as node ids to play with). Do I need to inherit a great grandparent and start fresh? I'm guessing I'll need to further explore dependency injections? Any thoughts on how to proceed in general or in detail? I'm flexible with answers as long as it helps me overcome this stuck point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom widget.

Edit your field and set the "**reference method**" from "**default**" to "**Views: filter by an entity reference view**". It will then tell you the following (if there are no entity reference views defined yet):

> No eligible views were found. Create a view with an Entity Reference
>   display, or add such a display to an existing view.

So then you go ahead and create that entity reference view (/admin/structure/views), go back to your field and select it again, now you should be able to pick the view and voilá.

When you create the entity reference view, you can define which entity fields to display (instead of the entity title or additionally to it - which is exactly what you want). So actually you don't need to write any code for that functionality, it's all configuration.

**EDIT:**

As figured out by asker, this does not work out of the box. I found a module which enables the desired functionality (the form widget for the entity reference view):

https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_views_select

This module seems only to enable the select and checkbox widget for the entity reference view.

If a more sophisticated configuration is desired, the entity browser: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser 
is also under heavy development, as it seems. (both untested by myself)

Comment: This technique is exactly what I tried initially and it seemed to "work" (almost). While my entity reference views display successfully filtered and sorted options available in my "Check boxes/radio buttons" widget, anything I placed in the fields section of the view was ignored and I would always see entity titles, nothing else (image or otherwise, even altered title). This led me to further explore the widget itself. Am I wrong on this? I'll follow up with screenshots following your answer suggestions.

Comment: Here are some quick screenshots: - 1. [view display](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7718/26860878420_27e5ffef59_o.png) - 2. [view display preview](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7244/26531073483_86fa11a20b_o.png) 
- 3. [edit entity reference field](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7627/27040390782_ce6c267ed6_o.png) 
- 4. [choose form display widget](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7611/26860878390_2f07342de8_o.png) 
- 5. [add content form results](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7442/27040390722_5460c54936_o.png)

Comment: Entity Reference Views Select module did the trick, offering exactly what I needed. While Drupal 8 is still "new", I should have known that there was likely already a module for that. No need to reinvent something that is already covering what I need and I'll gladly accept this as the correct answer.