# How to customize referenced taxonomy term in custom content type form

Tags: drupal-8, taxonomy-terms

I'm new to drupal and need some help .

## Context :

In drupal 8, I have a custom content type 'projet' with a custom field referenced a custom taxonomy term list .

The taxonomy term have a title and description  (default fields).
In the 'add projet' form (route /node/add/projet) for the linked entity field and need to display checkbox list (this is working) displaying the title and the description. I can't find how to acheive this .

## Tested configuration :

- I have already test to change display and form display settings on the custom content type (route : /admin/structure/types/manage/projet/form-display)
- also tried to change the display setting on taxonomy management
  (route : /admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/axe_de_travail/overview/display )

## Screenshoot :

For now on route /node/add/projet I have my taxonomy field displayed as

actual display:

[image]

What I expected is:

[image]

Comment: please read [ask] and share some code pls.

Comment: I'm sorry I was thinking to be the clearest I could. I have no code. it's just back end configuration. I have added screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal 8: How do I customize a form widget to show an entity field value instead of the entity title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335237/drupal-8-how-do-i-customize-a-form-widget-to-show-an-entity-field-value-instead)